# Rails POST base64 image data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I'm experiencing some interesting behavior when trying to send base64 encoded `.png` data to my controller.

#### my_controller.rb

```
def post_the_data
  require 'base64'

  return render :json => {
    :success => false,
    :message => 'you need to specify the data and module parameter.'
  } unless params[:data] && params[:module]

  file = "#{Rails.root}/public/pics/pics#{params[:module]}.png"

  png = Base64.decode64(params[:data])

  File.open(file, 'wb') { |f| f << png }

  if File.exist?(file)
    render :json => {
      :success => true
    }
  else
    render :json => {
      :success => false,
      :message => 'something went wrong when saving ' + file
    }
  end
end
```

In my shell, i am taking a [100x100px image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMiol.png) and simply executing:

```
curl --data "module=HI&data=`cat ~/Pictures/yo.png | base64`" http://localhost:3000/api/pics/pics
```

which will take my yo.png (the url linked above) and convert it to base64

I then do a `open workspace/rails4dashboard/qa-dashboard/public/pics/picsHI.png`

Interesting part is, when i execute that, it opens the file, but it's Blank!  The picture is 100x100, but has no pixel data inside?

What is happening! (I've already validated routing is *not* the issue.)

Comment: Have you checked for newline issues? Sometimes base64 contains newlines and sometimes it doesn't, newlines interacting with back ticks and the shell could be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that:

```
png = Base64.decode64(params[:data].gsub(/\n/, '').gsub(' ', '+'))
```

Explanation:

Base64.decode64 some times adds newlines to the string, we should remove them.

Rails replaces + with a space at params, replace it back to +.

Was with the same issue. This solved my problem.